# Can't get Platform Event Retries to work?

Tags: exception, platform-event

I am not seeing any evidence that processing continues after I raise a EventBus.RetryableException.

Logs indicate the retry event is thrown, then nothing. My test class, which is the same as indicated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_test_retry.htm), never demonstrate a Retries value other than 0.

```
EventBusSubscriber[] subscribers = [SELECT Name, Type, Position, Retries, LastError FROM EventBusSubscriber WHERE Topic='myEvent']
```

What could I be missing? The exception is raised in a services class within a trigger framework.

```
if (upsertList.size() > 0) {
    Database.UpsertResult [] upsertResults = Database.upsert(upsertList, myObject__c.Fields.External_ID__c, false);
    Database.UpsertResult aResult = null;
    for (Integer i=0; i<upsertResults.size(); i++) {
        aResult = upsertResults[i];
        if (!aResult.isSuccess()) {
            // Retry if Course Attempt is not yet there (and any other db errors)
            for (Database.Error err : aResult.getErrors()) {
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, THISISME + ' - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ': ' + err.getFields());

                if (err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.INVALID_FIELD && err.getMessage().contains('External_Id__c') && EventBus.TriggerContext.currentContext().retries < 4) {
                        throw new EventBus.RetryableException('Retying myEvent (' + EventBus.TriggerContext.currentContext().retries + ')');
                } else {
                    busExcLog.log_bulk(PEBusinessExcLog.ERROR, 'Upsert', String.valueOf(upsertList[i].External_ID__c.split('_')[0]), THISISME,
                                       'Upsert event had an error processing: '+ String.valueOf(err),
                                       JSON.serializePretty(upsertList[i]));
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, THISISME + ' - Upsert Successful: ' + JSON.serializePretty(upsertList[i]));
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm.  When I implemented this feature, it worked just fine.  Use [edit] and post your (relevant portions only) code

Comment: Are you saying that you never see the events retried on a subsequent transaction?  Note events run as Automated Process user.

Comment: Yes, I never see them again. Processing appears to just halt when the exception is raised.

Comment: And your trigger is at V46?

Comment: Yes, triggers and classes are all API v46

Comment: Perhaps I'm throwing the exception to far down the stack?

Comment: You aren't catching this exception higher up?

Comment: really? if you're catching any exception thrown by this method, then SFDC will never know about it.  Better would be to throw a user-defined exception `RaceConditionException` and then have the higher level catch block throw `EventBusRetryableException`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to be misled by the documentation for the `EventBus.RetryableException` to lull one into thinking that SFDC intercepts this immediately and retries the platform events (plus any new ones that have shown up).

However, like any exception that you throw, if you have a higher-in-the-stack try-catch construct, then like any thrown exception, including OOTB exceptions, you will catch it and unless you rethrow it back to SFDC, you are effectively eating your own attempt at coercing a retry.

A useful pattern might be in this case

**top level class/trigger**

```
try {
  doWork();
}
catch (MyTransientException mtx) {
   if (EventBus.TriggerContext.currentContext().retries < 4) {
     throw new EventBusRetryableException(mtx.getmessage());
   else {
      doSomething();
   }
catch (Exception e) { 
      doSomethingLikeLogOrRollback();
}
```

**and in the class that detects the transient condition ..**

```
if (someConditionIsTransient) {
   throw new MyTransientException('waiting on a foo to show up, will retry');
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks cropredy. My issue was a generic exception handler intercepting the retry and basically quashing it. Removing this allowed SF to detect and process it.